# Is it possible to suppress clang warnings in Jenkins?

Tags: ios, jenkins, warnings, clang

I have an iOS project that uses a number of 3rd party Libraries -- these cause a large number warnings when I build the project in both Xcode and Jenkins, I have checked and I'm happy to ignore these warnings. I have had a look and set the following compile flags on each of the classes but to no avail:

`-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker`

Any ideas how can I can suppress these warnings on a per class basis? I'm not particularly worried about xcode but suppressing them in Jenkins is key.

I am using Xcode 4.4 and LLVM compiler

Thanks...

Comment: It is not clear if you wish to hid those messages from the log (because it gets too big to follow) or just ignore them as possible errors. The solution varies depending on your intent.

Comment: Ideally I just want to be able to ignore them - but only for specific classes that I know are 3rd party and have no interest in amending.

Answer (score 0):

To **hide** those messages from the log, you will need to prevent them from being sent to STDOUT
(You will have to manage this from your build-script).

To **ignore** those messages, there is not much to do -
those messages don't cause your build to fail, I presume,
because Jenkins ignores the content of the log by default,
and determines the outcome of your build by the return-code
of the last command executed in that Jenkins-job.

Comment: any idea how to prevent the warning on Jenkins Log

Comment: The warnings in the log are the output of what you are running - it is not determined by Jenkins. Try changing the log-level of the tool you are running in the job (build-script or whatever).